# How do I pick out one hstore column from a group in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, hstore

Suppose I have a table `foo` in Postgres 11.5:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (an_int integer, a_varchar varchar(50));
```

I can select columns unique by integer and grab a couple of the `a_varchar` values as samples as follows:

```
SELECT an_int,
       min(a_varchar) min_a_varchar,
       max(a_varchar) max_a_varchar
FROM foo
GROUP BY 1;
```

Suppose I have a table `foo2` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE foo2 (an_int integer, an_hstore hstore);
```

Is there a similar way to select one row per `an_int`and pluck out one or more  [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) values? I tried using `hstore_to_json()` and it didn't work.  Converting to `varchar` did work, but I don't know if that preserves data well.

So my best answer so far:

```
SELECT an_int,
       min(an_hstore::varchar) min_an_hstore,
       max(an_hstore::varchar) max_an_hstore
FROM foo2
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: `select one row per an_int` - ***any*** row? I doubt you need the "minimum hstore", that would be a very exotic requirement.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to define `min` and `max` for `hstore`.

Here is an example for `min`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hstore_smaller(hstore, hstore) RETURNS hstore
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT CASE WHEN $2 IS NULL OR $1 #<# $2 THEN $1 ELSE $2 END';

CREATE AGGREGATE min(hstore) (
   STYPE = hstore,
   SFUNC = hstore_smaller
);
```

Then you don't have to use any casts.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just want to pick ***N*** rows ***arbitrarily*** for each distinct value of `an_int`. (Not "the minimum/maximum hstore".)

For ***1*** row per group:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (an_int) an_int, an_hstore
FROM  foo2;
```

For ***N*** rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY an_int) AS rn FROM foo2) sub
WHERE  rn < 3;
```

If the pick shall be deterministic instead of arbitrary, define your criteria and add `ORDER BY` clauses accordingly. Can also be "the minimum or maximum hstore" as `ORDER BY an_hstore` works out of the box - internally using those undocumented `hstore` operators Laurenz uses to create an aggregate function in another answer, which is smart, but also slow.

Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Performance optimization for *many* rows per group:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)